# Issue with Delphi Menu

Tags: delphi

I am Using RAD Studio 2010 and I have problem in Menu text

There are Z and Y texts in my menu and I want to remove it

This will happen when I use Non English text

[image]

Comment: This is actually an interesting question because it is about localisation and non-Latin-based languages. But it would be very helpful if you would include a description of how accelerator keys work in your language (like `&File` > `&Save` for menu items or `&Save` for a button).

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could edit the question and include text for the menu captions. Reproducing issue from the picture alone, is impossible for all but native speakers of the language in question.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Actually, the precise text doesn't matter. You can just use a few animals: گربه ها
سگ ها
پرنده ها
فیل ها
موش
خرگوش

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [`TMainMenu.AutoHotkeys`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMainMenu.AutoHotkeys). By default, the value of this property is `maAutomatic`, which means that the menu will automatically choose accelerator keys for your menu items.

For instance, in a typical English application, you might get a menu like this:

[image: Screenshot of an English Win32 application with a menu bar. The menu items are File, Edit, Find, View, Insert, and Options, and each item has an underlined character.]

Notice the underlined characters. These are used to access the menu using the keyboard. For instance, to open the `File` menu, I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. And once the `File` menu is open, I can press the key corresponding to the underlined character in the caption of the menu item I wish to invoke.

For keyboard users like myself, such accelerators are extremely important. I use them all the time. I could use the mouse instead, but that would slow me down tremendously. (For instance, in the application in the screenshot, I am very used to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to open the **Sort Lines** dialog box. That takes about 0.2 seconds. If I had to use the mouse, it would take *much* longer!)

Now, in your case, there aren't any Latin letters to underline, so instead the RTL adds these parentheses (with the Latin letter being the accelerator), so you still can access the menus using the keyboard.

I have very little experience with non-Latin-based versions of Windows, but I do believe menus like these are standard. If I were a Chinese or Arabic user (for instance), I think I would refuse to use an application without these. If I cannot access GUI menus and controls with the keyboard, I get really annoyed.

Still, if you insist, you can set `AutoHotkeys` to `maManual`.

Comment: After some quite extensive Googling, I can find a lot of examples of Chinese-language applications using this approach, but not a single Arabic example.

Comment: Actually, I am beginning to suspect that accesskeys in Persian and Arabic GUIs should work like in Latin GUIs (with a Persian or Arabic letter being underlined). Do we have any Persian or Arabic users here that can confirm?

Comment: I have come to the painful realisation that I know far too little about non-Latin languages in general and UIs in particular.

Comment: It boils down to the [(Arabic) keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Arabic): if a letter can be typed thru one key then it's useful for accelerator keys. Although [Kana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Japanese) would also fit the I encountered only japanese program GUIs that had [separate latin letters for menu entry accelerator keys](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/145391iA20B8B1A8B8EAB4E/).

Comment: @AmigoJack: Do you think it is wrong of the VCL to handle Persian (?) menus in this way (meaning that you need to set `AutoHotkeys = maManual` in Persian-language applications)?

Comment: I fear the VCL only supports/expects ASCII latin letters when trying to automatically handle accelerator chars: creating menu items with the captions `äöß` and `éô` won't auto-assign any letter in D7. **Hector** should just use a `&` per item (i.e. `برای& ویرایش`), as that itself [is supported without any problem](https://abload.de/img/20210222accelcharpersbqk7z.png).

Comment: In other words, if you make Persian apps, you must always set `AutoHotkeys = maManual` because the automatic handling doesn't support Persian?

Comment: Can take a look at the code in TMenuItem's InternalRethinkHotkeys to see what is going on. It uses a string of valid hotkeys with a comment to not localize. The string is  `1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Comment: True, I did check that. But the real question isn't what the VCL is doing (that's pretty obvious), but what the norm is in Persian software.